# Does Demogorgon have a stat block in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

My friends got into D&D through *Stranger Things* and as the final boss of a campaign I'm writing I think Demogorgon (D&D's Demogorgon, not like the one in the show) would be a fitting end to a long struggle.

He's mentioned on page 51 of the *Monster Manual* but it gives no stats. Where can I find Demogorgon's stats?

(To clarify I do not want to find the stat block for the *Stranger Things* demogorgon.)

Answer (score 27):

### Demogorgon is detailed in Out of the Abyss

The stat block for Demogorgon can be found on page 236 of the hardback book "[Out of the Abyss](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/outoftheabyss)", by Wizards of the Coast. He is not an encounter for the faint of heart.

A generic description of the demon prince in an historical and 5th edition context can be found on the Wizards site, [here](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/demogorgon-prince-demons).

Answer (score 11):

Yes.

Demogorgon's stat block and description is described in-depth in the campaign book *Out of the Abyss*.

Each of the demon lords are described in the appendices of this campaign book, including Demogorgon, known as the "Prince of Demons".

Comment: thank you so much. its the end of the campaign so if they die its not much of a problem. they should be at a pretty high level by then so maybe they'll stand a chance.

Comment: Since the question has changed again, i need to remove my downvote but can't?

Comment: @gburton Edits are locked in until an edit happens. I happen to have edited this for punctuation and formatting, so you can change your vote now should you wish. :)

Answer (score 11):

[The stat block is for sale on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/demogorgon). A la carte it is $1.99 so you don't have to buy the whole book "Out of the Abyss."

Answer (score 10):

The stat block and description can be found on page 144-145 of *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*.